# Override a method and make it behave static

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have an existing framework, which I can't change, it reads 2 properties

- `ClassA=somepackage.AnImplementationOfInterfaceA`
- `ClassB=somepackage.AnImplementationOfInterfaceB`

Which calls `public methodA` on a `new ClassA()`, `public methodB` on a `new ClassB()` in that order

I want to make a `class C` which implements interfaces A, B and provides hooks `methodC1`, `methodC2` for `class D` to override (`methodA` & `methodB` contain a lot of boilerplate and complex to implement - `methodC1` & `methodC2` would encapsulate the business logic) . Then my properties would be

- `ClassA=somepackage.classD`
- `ClassB=somepackage.classD`

The problem is that the person who implements class D might be tempted to write something like:

```
class D extends class C
{
   private int foo; //must be non-static due to multi-threaded new Class D() calls going on
   int methodC1() {this.foo = read number from network}
   methodC2(int x) {y = this.foo;} //methodC2 is always called after methodC1

   //methodA, methodB implementation inherited from C
}
```

But this wouldn't work as expected since the framework would actually create a new object of `class D` each time before invoking `methodA`, `methodB` and thus can't rely on using the "this" reference.

Defining `methodC1`, `methodC2` as `static` wouldn't work either because then the call to `methodC1` is tied to the implementation in `C`, not the overriden one in `D`.

When really what ought to be written is:

```
class D extends class C
{
   int methodC1() {return number from network;}
   methodC2(int x) {y = x}  //here y is using the return value of methodC1

   //methodA, methodB implementation inherited from C
}
```

I would also like *only* `methodC1`, `methodC2` to be overridable i.e. programmers working on D can't mess with `methodA`

The ideal design would have

- the properties refer to one class only
- `methodC1`, `methodC2` to be in that class

Summary of challenges

- no `this` in `methodC1`, `methodC2`
- can't make `methodC1`, `methodC2` `static`
- properies takes only a instantiable class

How do I design this framework? Is this even solvable? You can change the signature of `methodC1`, `methodC2`.

Comment: You can not make static methods overridable.

Comment: Yes. The crux of my design problem seems to be restricting a method from using "this" but making it overridable.

Answer (score 0):

Composition! Establish an interface that you are okay with people extending.

This class would contain the logic for MethodD1 and D2, and for everything else just a simple call to the other methods in your currently existing class. People won't be able to modify the calls to change the underlying logic.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you're saying is: define class E containing methodC1, methodC2. And class C has a member E e. Then C would call e.methodC1() and e.methodC2()? But the problem is how do I get e "into" C? The framework calls new C().methodA() and then new C().methodB() on it when I set the properties.

Answer (score 0):

The static methods can not be overridden!

If a subclass defines a static method with the same signature as a static method in the superclass, the method in the subclass hides the one in the superclass. The distinction between hiding and overriding has important implications.